# mesos-dns, best practice for working with ports

Tags: dns, mesos, service-discovery, mesosphere, marathon

I am quite new to Service Discovery and clustered systems. I started experimenting with Mesos and Marathon for the deployment of Docker containers, the Marathon REST API and UI seem to do a good job.

My problem is the actual discovery of deployed services. For testing purposes I deployed a Kafka Cluster scaled to 3 instances via Marathon, as so I did with a MongoDB test-cluster. The Mesos-DNS client gives me a record like `kafka.marathon.mesos` and `mongo.marathon.mesos` which implies the dynamically mapped port from the host to the container. The problem is, that my client explicitly needs information about the target port. Is there a general way to get those port information from the service automatically and dymanically? What about apps exposing multiple ports?

My thougts so far: 
- Doing a REST call to get a status about the deployed app and somehow extract the relevant data
- Doing a DNS SRV lookup and somehow extract the relevant data
- Having some kind of "master", statically bound to a port, with dynamic "clients".

I searched a lot for those informations but in the end most of the tutorials ended with a manual lookup which is not what I aim for.

Answer (score 2):

You're spot on. I recently gave a [presentation](https://xebicon.nl/slides/michael-hausenblas.pdf) at XebiCon around this topic and plan to publish a blog post with details about the setup incl. GitHub repo. For starters you could have a look at a [Python implementation](https://github.com/mhausenblas/mc) for the HTTP API consumption part.

UPDATE: the blog post is now available [here](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2015/06/21/web-application-analytics-using-docker-and-marathon/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will have a look!